# How to reconstruct a Dataframe from a groupby object?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I would like to apply a different transformation to each hour of a time series of hourly frequency (in the example a simple multiplication by different coefficients).

My attempt to a solution uses a groupby and then applies the transformation to each group.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create the time series
index = pd.date_range('10/1/1999', periods=1100,freq='h')
ts1 = pd.Series(np.random.normal(0.5, 2, 1100), index).rolling(window=100,min_periods=100).mean().dropna()
ts2 = pd.Series(np.random.normal(0.5, 2, 1100), index).rolling(window=100,min_periods=100).mean().dropna()

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':ts1,'B':ts2})

# create the coefficients
dayindex = pd.date_range('10/1/1999', periods=24,freq='h')
dayts = pd.Series(np.random.normal(0.5, 2, 24), dayindex)
#dayts = pd.Series(np.zeros(24), dayindex)


# define the function
def multiplycoeff(value, coeff):
    return value*coeff

# group by time
grouped_df = df.groupby(lambda x: x.time())

final = pd.DataFrame()
temp = pd.DataFrame()
for key, item in grouped_ts:
    #print str(key) +' -> '+ str(dayts[key])
    temp = grouped_df.get_group(key).apply(multiplycoeff, coeff = dayts[key])
    final = final.append(temp)

# the data frame is empty
print final
```

Output:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

---

**EDIT:**

I corrected as suggested by root. The output is now

```
                      A   B
1999-10-01 00:00:00 NaN NaN
1999-10-06 00:00:00 NaN NaN
1999-10-07 00:00:00 NaN NaN
1999-10-08 00:00:00 NaN NaN
1999-10-09 00:00:00 NaN NaN
1999-10-10 00:00:00 NaN NaN
1999-10-11 00:00:00 NaN NaN
```

---

The transformation works on a time series but doesn't on the DataFrame (tested with the zero time series )

The questions are:

1. Is this the right way to do it? Would in this case a .transform() be more elegant and/or more appropriate?
2. How do I reconstruct the original DataFrame after the transformation, as .append() does not seem to be the answer?

**EDIT 2**

Testing the same with a time series leads to the first (00:00:00) and last hour (23:00:00) to be multiplied by the coefficient. The rest is NaN

```
# create the time series
index = pd.date_range('10/1/1999', periods=1100,freq='h')
ts = pd.Series(np.random.normal(0.5, 2, 1100), index).rolling(window=100,min_periods=100).mean().dropna()


# create the coefficients
dayindex = pd.date_range('10/1/1999', periods=24,freq='h')
dayts = pd.Series(np.random.normal(0.5, 2, 24), dayindex)
#dayts = pd.Series(np.zeros(24), dayindex)


# define the function
def multiplycoeff(value, coeff):
    return value*coeff

# group by time
grouped_ts = ts.groupby(lambda x: x.time())

final = pd.Series()
for key, item in grouped_ts:
    #print str(key) +' -> '+ str(dayts[key])
    temp = grouped_ts.get_group(key).apply(multiplycoeff, coeff = dayts[key])
    final = final.append(temp)

# the series is half-empty
print final
```

output:

```
                      0  1999-10-01 00:00:00  1999-10-01 01:00:00  \
1999-10-06 00:00:00 NaN            -0.711597                  NaN   
1999-10-07 00:00:00 NaN            -1.078877                  NaN   
1999-10-08 00:00:00 NaN            -0.846465                  NaN   
1999-10-09 00:00:00 NaN            -0.782272                  NaN   
1999-10-10 00:00:00 NaN            -0.770075                  NaN  
....
1999-11-09 23:00:00                  NaN             0.033394  
1999-11-10 23:00:00                  NaN            -0.141565  
1999-11-11 23:00:00                  NaN             0.307111  
1999-11-12 23:00:00                  NaN             0.689724  
1999-11-13 23:00:00                  NaN             0.954596  
1999-11-14 23:00:00                  NaN             1.452619
```

Comment: I don't know if this is the entire issue, but `append` is not an inplace operation, so you need to reassign, i.e. `final = final.append(temp)`.

Comment: thanks for pointing out. I corrected as you suggest but the problem now is that the `final` DataFrame contains only NaN. the problem seems to be in the `temp = grouped_df.get_group(key).apply(multiplycoeff, coeff = dayts[key])` line